# What is the proper way to organize a Julia source tree?

Tags: julia

I am trying to figure the proper way to organize the source tree for a Julia application `seqscan`. For now I have the following tree:

```
$ tree seqscan/
seqscan/
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── benchmark
├── doc
├── examples
├── src
│   └── seq.jl
└── test
    └── test_seq.jl

5 directories, 4 files
```

The file `seq.jl` contains

```
module SeqScan
module Seq

export SeqEntry

type SeqEntry
    id
    seq
    scores
    seq_type
end

end
end
```

and `test_seq.jl` contains:

```
module TestSeq

using Base.Test
using SeqScan.Seq

@testset "Testing SeqEntry" begin
    @testset "test SeqEntry creation" begin
        seq_entry = SeqEntry("test", "atcg")
        @test seq_entry.id == "test"
        @test seq_entry.seq == "atcg"
    end
end

end
```

However, running the test code yields an error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Module SeqScan not found in current path.
```

even after setting the `JULIA_LOAD_PATH` environment variable to include `seqscan` or `seqscan/src`, so I must be doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you restart Julia after modifying the load path?  Also, I think you want the module name to match both the directory and the file name.

Comment: I ran the `test_seq.jl` file from the command line and not the REPL, Do we have any concrete info on the module/dir/file name mapping? - I don't see that in the docs

Comment: See http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/modules/ about naming and file paths.  If the module is on your path you would use it with `using TestSeq` in the REPL or in a script rather than running the main script file from the command line.  Take a look at the structure of existing Julia packages in your package directory: http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/packages/

Comment: I am not writing a module - I am writing an application to be run from the command line. The docs are patchy on using/import with respect to the source tree :o/

Comment: Apparently module names and file names must match in a case insensitive manner and with optional .jl suffix. Those matching rules should be documented ...

Comment: Bah, it is only the root level that is case insensitive!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40269430/how-does-julia-using-behave-on-missing-package

Answer (score 2):

The name of your package (the root of your local tree) needs to match the name of a file that exists under the src directory.  Try this:

```
SeqScan/
    |-- src/
         |-- SeqScan.jl (your seq.jl)
```

I don't know why you are enclosing the module Seq in SeqScan.  If there is no important reason to do that, you could access the type more directly.  You could remove "module Seq" and the paired "end".  Then just "using SeqScan" would bring in the type SeqEntry.

The type, SeqEntry, as written knows what to do when given four field values, one for each of the defined fields.  If you want to initialize that type with just the first two fields, you need to include a two-argument constructor. For example, assuming seq is a vector of some numeric type and scores is also a vector of that numeric type and and seq_type is a numeric type:

```
 function SeqEntry(id, seq)
     seq_type = typeof(seq[1])
     scores   = zeros(seq_type, length(seq))
     return SeqEntry(id, seq, scores, seq_type)
 end
```

An example of a package with internal modules, for Julia v0.5.

The package is named MyPackage.jl; it incorporates two internal modules: TypeModule and FuncModule; each module has its own file: TypeModule.jl and FuncModule.jl.

TypeModule contains a new type, MyType. FuncModule contains a new function, MyFunc, which operates on variable[s] of MyType.  There are two forms of that function, a 1-arg and a 2-arg version.

MyPackage uses both internal modules. It incorporates each for immediate use and initializes two variables of MyType.  Then MyPackage applies MyFunc to them and prints the results.

I assume Julia's package directory is "/you/.julia/v0.5" (Windows: "c:\you.julia\v0.5"), and refer to it as PkgDir. You can find the real package directory by typing Pkg.dir() at Julia's interactive prompt.  The first thing to do make sure Julia's internal information is current: `> Pkg.update()` and then get a special package call PkgDev: `> Pkg.add("PkgDev")`

You might start your package on GitHub. If you are starting it locally, you should use PkgDev because it creates the essential package file (and others) using the right structure:
`> using PkgDev` then `> PkgDev.generate("MyPackage","MIT")`
*This also creates a file, LICENSE.md, with Julia's go-to license.  You can keep it, replace it or remove it.*

In the directory PkgDir/MyPackage/src, create a subdirectory "internal". In the directory PkgDir/MyPackage/src/internal, create two files: "TypeModule.jl" and "FuncModule.jl", these:

TypeModule.jl:

```
module TypeModule
    export MyType

    type MyType
        value::Int
    end

end # TypeModule
```

FuncModule.jl:

```
module FuncModule

    export MyFunc

    #=
     !important!
     TypeModule is included in MyPackage.jl before this module
     This module gets MyType from MyPackage.jl, not directly.
     Getting it directly would create mismatch of module indirection.
    =#
    import ..MyPackage: MyType

    function MyFunc(x::MyType)
        return x.value + 1
    end

    function MyFunc(x::MyType, y::MyType)
        return x.value + y.value + 1 
    end

end # FuncModule
```

And in the src directory, edit MyPackage.jl so it matches this:

MyPackage.jl:

```
module MyPackage

    export MyType, MyFunc

    #=
      !important! Do this before including FuncModule
      because FuncModule.jl imports MyType from here.
      MyType must be in use before including FuncModule.
    =#       
    include( joinpath("internal", "TypeModule.jl") )
    using .TypeModule # prefix the '.' to use an included module

    include( joinpath("internal", "FuncModule.jl") ) 
    using .FuncModule # prefix the '.' to use an included module

    three = MyType(3)
    five  = MyType(5)

    four  = MyFunc(three)
    eight = MyFunc(three, five)

    # show that everything works
    println()
    println( string("MyFunc(three) = ", four) )   
    println( string("MyFunc(three, five)  = ", eight) )   

end # MyPackage
```

Now, running Julia entering `> using MyPackage` should show this:

```
julia> using MyPackage

        4 = MyFunc(three)
        9 = MyFunc(three, five)

julia>
```

Comment: I want to use modules to define namespaces, one for the project and nested within this different modules for the different functional components.

Comment: The current version of Julia does not support namespaces.  You can use different modules to fake it only if there are no exports that share the same name (or there will be clashes that Julia will not know how to resolve).  If you use different modules and always use full module-qualified name of a thing, you may be ok ... but that will get more thorny than Julia wants to be.  You may be much happier with giving different functional components their appropriately unique names, implementing them in their own subordinate files and using _include_ inside SeqScan.jl.

Comment: Suppose you have two components and each is single function: one is called _dothis_ and the other is called _dothat_.  You still have the file SeqScan.jl located here <yourstuff>/.julia/v0.5/SeqScan/src/SeqScan.jl. In the same directory, src, add DoThis.jl and DoThat.jl. DoThis.jl contains e.g. "function dothis(x) ... end"  and DoThat.jl similarly.  SeqScan.jl might be

     `module SeqScan`
         `export SeqEntry, dothis, dothat`
         `include("DoThis.jl")`
         `include("DoThat.jl")`
          `type SeqEntry ...`
     `end # module`

Comment: This seems to be a really clear explanation. I wonder why there isn't a relevant section on the Julia Documentation about properly structuring a project into different files. The current instructions are really confusing if one wants to break things into multiple parts. https://discourse.julialang.org/t/best-practices-for-structuring-larger-projects/2652/7