# How does Julia using behave on missing package?

Tags: julia

So what exactly does Julia do with the statement `using Foo` if you don't have package `Foo` installed? As I understood Julia starts searching `JULIA_LOAD_PATH`, but how?

At the root level of `JULIA_LOAD_PATH` there must be a directory named `Foo.jl` where the `Foo` part may be case insensitive and the `.jl` suffix is optional?

And within this `Foo.jl` directory there must be a source file name `Foo.jl` with a `module Foo`?

Comment: This be Julia 0.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`using` implicitly calls [`require`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/?highlight=require#Base.require) which indirectly calls [`find_in_path`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/ef460740f5c1177339086b79c7008454278159c7/base/loading.jl#L7-L27):

```
function find_in_path(name::AbstractString, wd = pwd())
    isabspath(name) && return name
    base = name
    # this is why `.jl` suffix is optional
    if endswith(name,".jl")
        base = name[1:end-3]
    else
        name = string(base,".jl")
    end
    if wd !== nothing
        isfile(joinpath(wd,name)) && return joinpath(wd,name)
    end
    for prefix in [Pkg.dir(); LOAD_PATH]
        path = joinpath(prefix, name)
        isfile(path) && return abspath(path)
        path = joinpath(prefix, base, "src", name)
        isfile(path) && return abspath(path)
        path = joinpath(prefix, name, "src", name)
        isfile(path) && return abspath(path)
    end
    return nothing
end
```

The source code above shows that there is no additional manipulation on `name`, which means the `Foo` part should be case **sensitive**(*Currently depend on the filesystem, see the comment below*). And the directory name is unnecessary to be compatible with your file name, it can be anything as long as the directory is in your `LOAD_PATH`.

Comment: Hm, case might be dependent on OS?

Comment: @maasha yes you're right, but this behavior may be changed as long as this [PR](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/18210) is merged.

Comment: I also think the "src" hardcoding is bad. May be addressed in Juleps: https://github.com/JuliaLang/Juleps/blob/master/Pkg3.md